# how to call jQuery plugin's method inside itself?

Tags: jquery, plugins

a jQuery plugin like this:

```
var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
        $("#something").click(function() {
            //call method show
        });
    },
    show: function() {
        //show something around here.
    }
}
```

..

how can i call the method `show` inside the method `init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which is like [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) only it doesn't need a shim for where it's not supported...

```
$("#something").click($.proxy(function() {
        // `this` is the same as `this` outside the function now.
        this.show();
    }, this));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a closure and capture the context of the current object (this):

```
init: function(options) {
    var _this = this;
    $('#something').click(function() {
        _this.show();
    });
}
```

or you could also use the [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method and pass arguments to the callback\

```
init: function(options) {
    $('#something').bind('click', { _this: this }, function(evt) {
        evt.data._this.show();
    });
}
```

or directly with the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method:

```
init: function(options) {
    $('#something').click({ _this: this }, function(evt) {
        evt.data._this.show();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your code shows that you want to call `show` inside of the click event of `#something`.

Second, when you're executing in the context of init, unless you say `methods.init.call(...)` with some other object in place of `...`, then `this` will be `methods`. Most likely, you will use the statement `methods.init()`. This is the correct assumption if you are just passing the object `methods` as a plugin to some jQuery widget. The following will work in this case:

```
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            this.show();
        },
        show: function() {}
    }
```

Unless you want to use the click event. In that case, use:

```
    var methods = {
        init: function(options) {
            $('#something').click(function() {
                this.show();
            }, this);  // propogate this into click handler
        },
        show: function() {}
    }
```

If you expect that you will run `methods.init.call(...)`, then you will need to make sure to set up a closure scope beforehand to keep track of the original `methods` object:

```
    var methods = function() {
        // setup closure scope
        var that = {};  // keep track of methods object
        that.init = function() {
            that.show();
        };
        that.show = function() {

        };

        // return object with closure scope... will become `methods`
        return that;
    }();
```